# Smartsync with Sencha Touch

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, salesforce-sencha, smartstore

Can I use SmartSync framework with Sencha Touch? I am new to Sencha Touch framework. Please help! I am looking for some starter pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin Poorman replied to your question at 10:31 PM on 7/17/2014.

Your question:
“Can I use SmartSync framework with Sencha Touch? I am new to Sencha Touch framework. Please help!”

Reply:
“SmartSync is, at it's core, a javascript library. When you create a hybrid app using forceios, you'll see it spit out smartsync.js

While Sencha touch likely doesn't have native interface(s) to integrate smartsync nicely, it's unlikely to conflict in a way that prevents smartsync from being used with sencha touch.”

Tip! To respond, either reply to this email or click this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000Ac5Y